# Athena - check if column a string contains column b string

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table with two columns, column A is a URL string and column B is a tracking id string. I need to check whether the tracking id string is included in the URL string, and then remove it from the URL string if so. Guessing it's quite straightforward but I just think of how do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with:

```
url like '%' || tracking || '%'
```

You could remove the substring with:

```
replace(url, tracking)
```

Frankly, **there is no need to check for the tracking ID first**, since if it isn't present, it simply won't be replaced, so you can just use the `replace(url, tracking)` command.

See: [6.9. String Functions and Operators — Presto Documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/string.html)